# Kohana 3.3 ORM table join

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I am looking for help specific to my question as I cant quite seem to get it right from the Kohana docs or googling.

I have 2 tables:

`contents`
id
uri
title
template_id

`templates`
id
title

I am trying to return all data for a `contents` row that has a matching *uri*.

Currently I have two models: Content and Template.

**Content**

```
class Model_Content extends ORM {
protected $_table_name = 'contents';
protected $_has_one = array('template' => array());
....
```

**Template**

```
class Model_Template extends ORM {

protected $_table_name = 'templates';
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'content' => array()
);
```

Then in my controller:

```
$item = ORM::factory("Content")->get_by_uri($uri);
```

which points to:

```
$this->where("uri", "=", $uri)->find();
```

This returns the data from the content table correctly but how can i bring in the template name from the template table?

Thanks for help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$item->template` is all you need. And dont forget to check model for existance: `if ($item->loaded())`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$this->template->find()`?

Comment: No. One-to-one (and belongs-to) relationship will be loaded automatically.